# how to handle backspace in uitextfield

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I have 6 uitextfield.And i did the autofocus. once user enter one value in one textfield.They will automatically redirect to next textfield. But i dont know how to handle the backspace .Like when user in last textfield and press backspace to delete the value..again they have to move to 5,4,3,2,1 respective textfields.How to do that ??

Here my code for autofocus :

```
@IBAction func editing(_ sender: UITextField)
    {


        if sender == TextFieldOne {
            if sender.text?.characters.count == 1 {
                TextFieldTwo.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }

        else if sender == TextFieldTwo {
            if sender.text?.characters.count == 1 {
                TextFieldThree.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }

        else if sender == TextFieldThree {
            if sender.text?.characters.count == 1 {
                TextFieldFour.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }
        else if sender == TextFieldFour {
            if sender.text?.characters.count == 1 {
                TextFieldFive.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }
        else if sender == TextFieldFive {
            if sender.text?.characters.count == 1 {
                TextFieldSix.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }

        else if sender == TextFieldSix {
            if sender.text?.characters.count == 1 {
                TextFieldSix.resignFirstResponder()
            }
        }




    }
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: if sender.text?.characters.count == 0 - that was a backspace

Comment: This link help for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642357/want-to-know-ever-time-while-pressing-on-keyboard-back-button-during-textfield-e

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

Remember `editing(_:)` action is bind using `EditingChanged` event.

```
if sender.text!.length == 0 {
       // textfield where you want to Focus.
       yourTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
 }
```

But I will suggest you to use below method of `UITextFieldDelegate`.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
// Array corresponding to the focus order of your textFields
let textFields = [TextFieldOne, TextFieldTwo, TextFieldThree, TextFieldFour, TextFieldFive, TextFieldSix]

func editing(_ sender: UITextField) {
    // Get sender index in textFields array
    guard let senderIndex = textFields.index(of: sender) else { return }

    // Char typed
    if sender.text?.characters.count == 1 {
        let nextTextFieldIndex = textFields.index(after: senderIndex)

        // Last textField: Remove focus
        if nextTextFieldIndex == textFields.count {
            textFields[senderIndex].resignFirstResponder()
        } else { // Other case: Focus next
            textFields[nextTextFieldIndex].becomeFirstResponder()
        }

    } else { // Char removed
        let previousTextFieldIndex = textFields.index(before: senderIndex)

        // If not first textField: Focus previous
        if previousTextFieldIndex != -1 {
            textFields[previousTextFieldIndex].becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't go to previous tf on tap on backspace as it's not standard in IOS. However here is the way you can achieve it:

In shouldchangecharacters method you need to identify if the tapped button is backspace, and then you use tags to identify each of the textfield seprately. So when you get the backspace you can get the previous textfield by decreasing the tag value from the current textfield and make the previous one the first responder.

It will be same for all the textfields so you don't have to use expensive if-else conditions to achieve it.